# Converting HTML to content_tag in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you convert this HTML into the Rails `content_tag` helper syntax/format?

```
<p class="msg">
    <span class="strong">Most people enjoy the inferiority of their best friends.</span>
    <br>
    <span class="emphasize"> - Lord Chesterfield</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

to be precise with classes added. You can also use blocks with content_tags if you have a bunch of lines.

```
content_tag(:p, :class => 'msg') do
  content_tag(:span, "Most ... friends.", :class => "strong") +
  content_tag(:br) + 
  content_tag(:span, "- Lord .. ", :class => "emphasize")
end
```

Comment: I like this.  This looks much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: You could also use "concat" instead of "+": http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/9123352587/nesting-content-tag-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
content_tag(:p, content_tag(:span,  'Most people enjoy the inferiority of their best friends.') + '<br/>' + content_tag(:span, ' - Lord Chesterfield'))
```